# magento 2 how to create confirgurable product with diffrent sizes with diffrent colors

Tags: magento2

How can we create configurable product according to this sizes and colors

Attribute name

**Sizes : Colors**
**XL : yellow, green**
**XXL : red, green**
**L : white, green**
**M : yellow, green**
**S : yellow, green**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get idea with this link.. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html

When we Add Configurations to new Configurable product. We can give more than one attribute to select.

In your case, you can select colour and size both attributes. Try and inform me.

Comment: i am selecting both attribute colors and sizes XL,L,S,M its  generating  product same color for every sizes. how can i select color according to sizes